# Platform unsupported

Tags: installation

I installed Blender 4.0 and it says that my graphics card is not supported.
Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600
20.19.15.5126
1-21-2020

OpenGL 4.3
Build 20.19.15.5126

DirectX 11.4

How can I use blender? Does my PC support blender? Which version should I install?

Thank you.

Comment: Which Windows version do you use? Blender 4 requires at least Windows 8 or Linux. The GPU should work. Have a look here: https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/

Comment: Thank you for your response, I use windows 10.